# Expiration of background tasks for lock screen provider apps

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a question on the expiration of background tasks. This article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx) under the "Constraints for all Scheduled Task Types" section states that the background agent will not expire if

- the app tile is pinned to the start screen and the background agent updates it
- the app is on the lockscreen and sends updates to the notifications (via ShellTile)
- the app is used to upload pictures similar to OneDrive

I wanted to ask how full lock screen providers are handled. My app only updates the lock screen image because that's the purpose the app should fulfill (it displays your/popular Instagram pictures on the lock screen). Are lock screen providers (if active) also automatically renewed? I do not send any tile updates (since it defeats the purpose of being a lock screen only app).

Does anyone know whether my task expires?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background Tasks are not expired. There might be a chance that your task might not run. User can disable the background task for your app or if the number of background tasks exceeds for your device. An **InvalidOperationException** will be thrown when the number of periodic background agents has reached the limit for the device or when disabled.

LockScreen providers are placed in background agents and not as ScheduledTasks.

> The code that runs in the background is placed in a class that derives from ScheduledTaskAgent, which derives from BackgroundAgent.

ScheduledTasks are reminders and alarms which will be expired subjected to those conditions you have mentioned in your question.

Refer to [Best Background agent practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

This condition is very important for your application as it download images in ResourceIntensiveTask:

> Caution : Due to the constraints on the device that must be met for
>   resource-intensive agents to run, it is possible that the agent will
>   never be run on a particular device. For example, if a user does not
>   have access to Wi-Fi or a PC, they may never have a non-cellular
>   connection and the resource-intensive agents on their device will
>   never run. Also, resource-intensive agents are run one at a time, so
>   as more applications that use resource-intensive agents are installed
>   on a device, the likelihood of an agent running becomes even less. You
>   should consider this when designing your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am still a bit confused. Currently I register a PeriodicTask and it seems these expire after 14 days. My whole lock screen updating logic is placed within the background agent and does not check whether it was the specific PeriodicTask that was called. Will my ScheduledAgent still be called after the PeriodicTask expires, or is this unrelated to registering the periodic task?

Comment: Periodic task wont expire. Reminders or alarms only expire after 14 days. Your background agent is classified as periodic or resource intensive in your foreground app and you need not worry about it. ScheduledAgent will call it when it meets the requirements.